# communication between modules in Prism4

Tags: wpf, prism-4

When communicating between modules, which approache is best in Prism4?
Although i have used Event Agregator.

Comment: What type of communiation do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your modules are across different assemblies, it is best to use Event Aggregator as you have done. This will ensure your modules are not tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

Event Aggregator is good, but some times is better to use common module with Interfaces for basic classes that you want to use into different modules. 
Another way is using Context for Regions/Views for communicating between UI elements